# Euler's Formula and Existence of Solids

Tags: graph-theory, 3d, polyhedra, solid-geometry

Euler's formula tells us that the number of vertices, edges and faces of a 3D solid have to satisfy the relationship $V+F=E+2$. How about the converse, if I have a triple of numbers that fulfill  this identity, how can I check if such solid (polyhedron) exists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converse of Euler's formula for polyhedra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278682/converse-of-eulers-formula-for-polyhedra)

Comment: No, because it does not specify a way on how to check the existence. It says counterexamples do exist, but not how to find positive example for a given triple of values.

Comment: I believe a result stated as a theorem in [Eulers Polyederformel, und die Arithmetisierung der Gestalt](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~blatter/Mathesis.pdf) on page 9., which is a resource linked by [Christian Blatter's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3279058/318073)  on the linked related question in the previous [comment by Shahab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3694186/eurlers-formula-and-existence-of-solids#comment7591981_3694186) answers your question.

Comment: I loved the spelling of Eurler in the headline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I followed the relevant (linked) resources and found the following.*

---

Every face has at least three sides $2E \ge 3F$, and at least three faces meet at a vertex $2E \ge 3V$. Combining this with the Euler's formula $V+F=E+2$ for convex polyhedra, one has:

$$2F - 4 \ge V \ge F/2 +2$$

And every such pair $(V,F)$ should correspond to at least one convex polyhedron.

> That is, it appears these necessary conditions are also sufficient: You only need to check these inequalities on top of the Euler's Formula to see if such polyhedron can exists or not.

I believe this answers your question.

---

If I'm not mistaken, this result is also stated as a theorem in [Eulers Polyederformel, und die Arithmetisierung der Gestalt](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~blatter/Mathesis.pdf) on page 9., which is a resource linked by [Christian Blatter's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3279058/318073)  on the related question which was linked in the [comments by Shahab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3694186/eurlers-formula-and-existence-of-solids#comment7591981_3694186).

*To see the intuition why it is sufficient, we observe a way to construct examples via truncation and expansion of pyramids and subsequently obtained polygons: (taken and shortened from [this article](http://web.iyte.edu.tr/~gokhankiper/Polyhedra/Euler.htm)):*

Every $n$-sided polygon based pyramid has $V=F=n+1$, $n\ge 3$.

- Truncating (a pyramid) at a vertex where three faces meet: $V\to V+2,F\to F+1$.
- Expanding on one of the triangular faces (of a pyramid): $V\to V+1,F\to F+2$.

Both operations may be applied infinitely, provided that the polyhedron remains convex. (As for non-convex polyhedra, the Eulers formula might fail $-$ see [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Polyhedra).)

---

---

*Remark;* Alternatively, You might be interested in the [Steinitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz%27s_theorem), cited from Wikipedia:

> "Steinitz's theorem is a characterization of the undirected graphs formed by the edges and vertices of three-dimensional convex polyhedra: they are exactly the (simple) 3-vertex-connected planar graphs."

Which is not needed for this particular question, but should be useful for similar problems.